# How to make an auto leveling menu

Tags: javascript, java, html, database, jsp

I want to build a website in which users can create a new menu tab
the system can identified level of the menu

I have written a simple code, but it is still manual, not automatic.
How do I make automatic leveling?

The menu data is stored in the database data, but the system must have the auto leveling menu.

Code:

```
<%
dataDB data = new dataDB();
dataMainMenu[] daftarMenu1 = data.getDaftarMenuByLevel1();
dataLinkMenu dataLink = new dataLinkMenu();
dataLinkMenu dataLink2 = new dataLinkMenu();
dataLinkMenu dataLink3 = new dataLinkMenu();
dataLinkMenu dataLink4 = new dataLinkMenu();
dataMainMenu dataMenu1 = new dataMainMenu();
dataMainMenu dataMenu2 = new dataMainMenu();
String []y=new String[daftarMenu.length];
dataDB max = new dataDB();
int a=0;
for(int j=0;j<daftarMenu1.length;j++){
    dataMenu2 = daftarMenu1[j];
    out.write(dataMenu2.getNama());
    dataLinkMenu[] daftarSubMenu = data.getLinkSubMenu(dataMenu2.getId());
    if(max.getMaxLevel()!=2){
        for (int i = 0; i < daftarSubMenu.length; i++) {
            dataLink = daftarSubMenu[i];
            out.write(dataLink.getSubMenu());
            dataLinkMenu[] daftarSubMenu1 = data.getLinkSubMenu(Integer.parseInt(dataLink.getSubMenu()));
            if(max.getMaxLevel()!=3) {
                for (int k = 0; k < daftarSubMenu1.length; k++) {
                    dataLink2 = daftarSubMenu1[k];
                    out.write(dataLink2.getSubMenu());
                    dataLinkMenu[] daftarSubMenu2 = data.getLinkSubMenu(Integer.parseInt(dataLink2.getSubMenu()));
                    if(max.getMaxLevel()!=4) {
                        for (int l = 0; l < daftarSubMenu1.length; l++) {
                            dataLink3 = daftarSubMenu2[l];
                            out.write(dataLink3.getSubMenu());
                            dataLinkMenu[] daftarSubMenu3 = data.getLinkSubMenu(Integer.parseInt(dataLink3.getSubMenu()));
                            if(max.getMaxLevel()!=5){
                                for (int m = 0; m < daftarSubMenu1.length; l++) {
                                    dataLink4 = daftarSubMenu3[l];
                                    out.write(dataLink4.getSubMenu());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        for (int l = 0; l < daftarSubMenu1.length; l++) {
                            dataLink3 = daftarSubMenu2[l];
                            out.write(dataLink3.getSubMenu());
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for (int k = 0; k < daftarSubMenu1.length; k++) {
                    dataLink2 = daftarSubMenu1[k];
                    out.write(dataLink2.getSubMenu());
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < daftarSubMenu.length; i++) {
            dataLink = daftarSubMenu[i];
            out.write(dataLink.getSubMenu());
        }
    }
    out.write("<br>");
}%>
```

any one can help?

Comment: You don't mind formatting that code some I hope?

Comment: emz, what do you meant?